# T-SQL Select row only if not exist already

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with two Ids, ResourceId and LanguageId

I need to join those two selects where second result would be added only if ResourceId not already in the list.

```
SELECT * FROM Resources WHERE Language = 1
SELECT * FROM Resources WHERE Language = 0

JOIN 
    /*where ResourceId not present already*/
```

So far I came up with nothing except complicated partitions. Is there better solution to this?

- Not all ResourceIds have Language 0 entry
- Not all ResourceIds have Language 1 entry
- Some ResourceIds have both

```
     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Resources](
            [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
            [ResourceId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
            [LanguageId] [int] NOT NULL,
            [Text] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
            [Path] [varchar](2000) NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_Resourcces] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [Id] ASC
        )WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a union with exists logic:

```
SELECT * FROM Resources WHERE Language = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Resources r1
WHERE
    Language = 0 AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Resources r2
                WHERE r2.Language = 1 AND r2.ResourceId = r1.ResourceId);
```

Comment: does not work sadly, lists only entries with Language = 1

Comment: @Fred But this is the precise logic you requested.  If `Language = 1` records _are_ found, then the `Language = 0` records should not be added to the result set.  Am I missing something, or did you maybe not word your question the way you wanted it?

Comment: **I need to join those two selects where second result would be added only if ResourceId not already in the list.** 
Meaning, add all with LanguageId = 1
add all with LanguageId= 0 where ResourceId is not already in the result

Comment: Right said Fred.  I updated my answer, thanks for explaining your full logic.

Comment: perfect, sounds right. Too simple to be embarassing enough for me.
Anyway if somebody finds something faster and simpler, i would love to see it

Comment: Well to the faster point, we can contemplate adding an index on `(ResourceId, Language)`, to make the exists subquery execute faster.

Comment: ok after some testing i can prove it is fast enough for me thanks @Tim-Biegeleisen

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . You do not need `UNION ALL` for this.  You can use `OR`.  That said, under some circumstances, the `UNION ALL` might optimize better.

Answer (score 0):

You can number the rows per `resourceid` by `languageid` using the `row_number()` window function and then just select the "first" one.

```
SELECT id,
       resourceid,
       languageid,
       text,
       path
       FROM (SELECT id,
                    resourceid,
                    languageid,
                    text,
                    path,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY resourceid
                                       ORDER BY languageid DESC) rn
                    FROM resources
                    WHERE languageid IN (0,
                                         1) x
       WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: this was close to my first solution but was too slow and complicated

Answer (score 0):

Since I had started answering but Tim was more effective than me, I still put my answer as you indicated that, and I quote:

> If somebody finds something faster and simpler, I would love to see it

```
USE TEST

CREATE DATABSE TEST

CREATE TABLE Ressources
(
RessourceId INT,
LanguageId INT
);

INSERT INTO Ressources
VALUES
(1,1),
(1,0),
(1,2),
(1,3),
(2,1),
(2,0),
(2,2),
(3,1),
(4,1),
(5,0)

WITH CTE_L1 AS (SELECT * FROM Ressources WHERE LanguageId = 1)
SELECT * FROM CTE_L1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Ressources
WHERE LanguageId = 0 
AND RessourceId NOT IN(SELECT RessourceId FROM CTE_L1)
```

Results I got:

```
RessourceId LanguageId
----------- -----------
1           1
2           1
3           1
4           1
5           0
```

(Same result if I execute the @Tim Biegeleisen query)

See which one you like best.

--> Cost of mine query 0.010132

--> Cost of Tim query 0.0100952

(Based on the execution plan)

Comment: This looks like it would be faster than Tims solution... I will test it

Comment: I don't really know if it is faster, just different statement. You should try with a lot of data

Comment: i cannot see any performance gain and optically Tims solution looks better. But thank you and thumbs up, it shows some knowledge.
Yes, Resources is few Mio entries big

Comment: You're welcome, glad to have been able to make a comparison.